# What's a good method to update the U.I in Unity after a player scores a point?

Tags: unity

I'm practicing with making a Pong clone and I've decided I want 2 large empty gameObjects on either side off camera to act as triggers to reset the game and add a point to either player's score, but Unity's U.I system confuses me.

Any help would be appreciated.[image]

Comment: Do you have any scripts already added? You won't achieve the gameplay result you want without coding that behavior. Of course you can either use JS/C# or visual scripting like Play Maker or Bolt. 

Using those above you will have an event that will kick in once the "ball" collides with the collider and at that moment you can update the Text field of the related Text component adding a point and reseting the ball.

Comment: I have this added to the PaddleScript:

public void AddScore()
    {
        _score += 1;
    }

and this added to the BallScript:

if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("KillPlane"))
        {           
            transform.position = startPosition;
            speed = 150f;
            _paddle.AddScore();
            Debug.Log("You Died");
        }

Comment: The position and speed reset successfully and the console logs the message, but the AddScore method won't interact at all.



In the Start method I tried assigning a variable:

_paddle = GameObject.Find("Paddle").GetComponent<PaddleScript>();

and that lets me add the AddScore(); but it won't function.

Comment: Sounds like you should add that code to your question with proper formatting, so folks don't have to parse it out of the comments.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually not uncommon for Unity UI code to just poll the current data in their Update method and change the text accordingly. For example, my standard approach to a UI widget which simply shows the score of a player would look something like that:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayerScoreDisplay : MonoBehaviour
{
      public Player player
      public Text text;

      void Update() {
           text.text = player.score.toString();
      }
}
```

It might seem a bit wasteful to update the UI every single frame even if nothing changed. A more efficient architecture might be to use some messaging architecture or the Observer pattern and only update the UI when the data actually changed. But the UI is usually the least performance-intense part of an Unity game. So unless you have really a lot of UI elements, that optimization isn't worth the effort and additional code complexity. And it would definitely be over-engineering for a simple Pong practice game.

Answer (score 0):

I use an event bus, which is basically the observer pattern, but many-to-many instead of 1-to-many.

You emit a "Scored" event from your player script, and the UI controller script picks it up and updates the UI. This way they the gameplay and UI logic stays completely decoupled.

Here is a small library I wrote for this purpose: https://github.com/starikcetin/Eflatun.EventBus

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in keeping your classes more organized. I would suggest you to segregate each class to be restricted to specific functionality.

One approach we used to do at work, was to do some sort of [**MVC (Model View Controller)**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mvc_framework/mvc_framework_introduction.htm) approach (of course, not as literal as the framework textually is) where we have a controller that has access to all or many elements of the game (in this casethe class Game, thast has references to the players and the UI) and makes use of the [**Observer Pattern**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27507384/implementing-observer-pattern-with-events) with delegates as Philipps also suggested.

Example (note that, for the sake of example, I ommited the inclusion of namespaces. Your approach of letting each player its score instead of the game having 2 scores is also correct, if not better):

```
public class Game : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Player player1;
    public Player player2;
    public UIController UIController;
    private int player1Score;
    private int player2Score;

    private void Start()
    {
        if(player1 == null || player2 == null) return;

        player1.onPlayerEvent += OnPlayerEvent;
        player2.onPlayerEvent += OnPlayerEvent;
    }

    private void OnPlayerEvent(Player player, int eventID)
    {
        switch(eventID)
        {
            case Player.ID_ADDSCORE:
            if(player == player1)
            {
                player1Score++;
                UIController.UpdatePlayerScore(1, player1Score);
            }
            if(player == player2)
            {
                player2Score++;
                UIController.UpdatePlayerScore(2, player2Score);
            }
            break;

            /*
            case 2:
            ...
            break;
            .
            .
            .
            case N:
            break;
            */
        }
    }
}

public class UIController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text player1ScoreText;
    public Text player2ScoreText;

    public void UpdatePlayerScore(int player, int score)
    {
        switch(player)
        {
            case 1:
            player1ScoreText.text = score.ToString();
            break;
            
            case 2:
            player2ScoreText.text = score.ToString();
            break;
        }
    }
}

public delegate void OnPlayerEvent(Player player, int eventID);

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public const int ID_ADDSCORE = 0;

    public event OnPlayerEvent onPlayerEvent;

    private void Update()
    {
        /// After conditions for the score to be updated are met:
        if(onPlayerEvent != null) onPlayerEvent(this, ID_ADDSCORE);
    }
}
```

But as Philipps mentioned already, the scope of your project is very simple, and a simple Update to fetch the players' score at every frame does not harm the performance at all.

Hope it helps, at least for the sake of having another perspective.